# How can I make a sturdy lightweight box?

Tags: wood

I want to build a box that is lightweight, but sturdy. At my disposal I have a laser-cutter, which I want to do the cutting.

My plan is as follows, but I have never done this. I have no idea if this will work, so I'm looking for some advice.

I want to cut the box sides out of wood with a laser cutter using notched edges. However, this wood will be thin and therefore will not be able to hold much weight. To improve the weight bearing capacity of this box I propose to add a layer of honeycomb polypropylene to the base and then add another layer of wood to maintain a rigid bottom surface, thus creating a sandwich of sorts. Does anyone think this will work?

Does anyone have an alternative idea?

Comment: This is a little sketchy, without a sketch.. If you post a link to a photo or drawing, I (we) can embed it for you until you get enough rep to do it yourself.

Comment: "a box that is lightweight, but sturdy" leads me to think of tin, not wood.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is very similar to how hollow core doors are made.

[image: Hollow Core Door]

If you feel a hollow core door is lightweight and sturdy enough for you, then I would say this approach will work for you.

Comment: If you have a [ReStore](http://www.habitat.org/env/restores.aspx) near you, you can probably find a hollow-core door for $5-10.  Cutting one up would be a *lot* less work than making one yourself.

Comment: In case you didn't know, the success or failure of this sort of construction is strongly dependent on the proper bond between veneers and core.